# AWS put-bucket-notification-configuration for SQS throws "Unable to validate the following destination configurations"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I want to send s3:CreateObject:* events to a SQS Queue. But setting up the notification configuration results in `A client error (InvalidArgument) occurred when calling the  PutBucketNotificationConfiguration operation: Unable to validate the following destination configurations`

This is the how I created the bucket:

```
aws s3api create-bucket --profile default --bucket my-bucket --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=eu-west-1
```

This is the how I created the SQS Queue

```
aws sqs create-queue --profile default --queue-name my-queue --attributes file://attributes.json
```

with the attributes.json file

```
{
  "DelaySeconds":"0",
  "MessageRetentionPeriod":"3600",
  "Policy":"{\"Statement\":[{\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":[\"sqs:SendMessage\",\"sqs:ReceiveMessage\"],\"Condition\":{\"ArnLike\": {\"aws:SourceArn\": \"arn:aws:s3:*:*:my-bucket\"}}}]}"
}
```

And finally the try to set up the notification which throws the error message I listed above:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-notification-configuration --profile default --bucket my-bucket --notification-configuration file://notification.json`
```

with the notification.json file

```
{
  "TopicConfigurations": [
  ],
  "QueueConfigurations": [
    {
      "QueueArn": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:123456789012:my-queue",
      "Events": [
        "s3:ObjectCreated:*"
      ],
      "Filter": {
        "Key": {
          "FilterRules": [
            {
              "Name": "prefix",
              "Value": "my-filter"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "LambdaFunctionConfigurations": [
  ]
}
```

I really have no clue where the error could be. 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I see you have "Filter" in your notification.json, and even though my JSON is for Lambda Config, it won't let me use "Filter" and says "Unknown Parameter, "Filter" must be one of: Id, LambdaFunctionArn, Events"
Did this ever work for you?

Comment: This solution works for me. [4457602](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66282120/4457602) Thanks, Gonzalo Gallotti!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your SQS policy is not working. Try to add `Id` to your policy and `Resource` to your statement. Something like this:

`{
  "DelaySeconds":"0",
    "MessageRetentionPeriod":"3600",
    "Policy":"{\"Id\":\"someid\",\"Statement\":[{\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Resource\": \"arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:123456789012:my-queue\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":[\"sqs:SendMessage\",\"sqs:ReceiveMessage\"],\"Condition\":{\"ArnLike\": {\"aws:SourceArn\": \"arn:aws:s3:*:*:my-bucket\"}}}]}"
}`

Here is more information:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ways-to-add-notification-config-to-bucket.html#step1-create-sqs-queue-for-notification

Also when calling API from command line, you can use --debug parameter. You would see full error message:

`aws --debug s3api ...`

Comment: Policy is a string so the JSON must be escaped in this case.

Comment: Just ran across this post and answer, I was experiencing a similar problem.  In my case I was re-using the same ID value from another bucket and that was the problem.  The `Id` must be unique across all buckets.

Comment: It worked. "Resource" and "Id" was missing

Answer (score 2):

I got a script that works.  I post it here for whomever else might be puzzling over this :-)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto3
import json

bucket_name='spike-bucket-000'
queue_name='spike_queue_000'
region='eu-west-1'

s3 = boto3.client('s3', region)
sqs = boto3.client('sqs', region)

def check_if_bucket_exists(name):
    s3.head_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)


try:
    check_if_bucket_exists(bucket_name)
    print('Bucket {} exists'.format(bucket_name))
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError:
    print('Creating bucket {}'.format(bucket_name))
    s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name, CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': region})

print('Ensuring queue {} exists'.format(queue_name))

response = sqs.create_queue(QueueName=queue_name)
queue_url = response['QueueUrl']
response = sqs.get_queue_attributes(QueueUrl=queue_url, AttributeNames=['QueueArn'])
queue_arn = response['Attributes']['QueueArn']

print('Granting bucket permission to post messages to queue')

queue_policy={
         "Version": "2008-10-17",
         "Id": "example-ID",
         "Statement": [
          {
           "Sid": "example-statement-ID",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal": {
            "AWS":"*"
           },
           "Action": [
            "SQS:SendMessage"
           ],
           "Resource": queue_arn,
           "Condition": {
              "ArnLike": {
              "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:" + bucket_name
            }
           }
          }
         ]
        }

sqs.set_queue_attributes(QueueUrl=queue_url, Attributes={'Policy': json.dumps(queue_policy)})

print('Configuring bucket to notify object creation to queue')

response = s3.put_bucket_notification_configuration(
    Bucket=bucket_name,
    NotificationConfiguration={
        'QueueConfigurations': [
            {
                'Id': 'Notify-ObjectCreated-To-Queue',
                'QueueArn': queue_arn,
                'Events': [
                    's3:ObjectCreated:*',
                ]
#               ,
#                 'Filter': {
#                     'Key': {
#                         'FilterRules': [
#                             {
#                                 'Name': 'prefix'|'suffix',
#                                 'Value': 'string'
#                             },
#                         ]
#                     }
#}
            },
        ]
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lubo Sach answer, I could get this working using this Policy in SQS:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "27097a52-cae3-49fe-84ce-0020893e394c",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__owner_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::9970XXXX4660:root"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:9970XXXX4660:bucketname"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "sqs:SendMessage",
        "sqs:ReceiveMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:9970XXXX4660:bucketname",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:bucketname"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

there needs to be a corresponding Lambda:Invoke permission; ensure that the Lambda has the permission over the bucket (it breaks if some Invoke:Permissions are given to bucket and keys)

Comment: The question is about SQS.